# ReSharper inline debugging like IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, resharper

I like the way variable values are outlined in IntelliJ IDEA as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/inline-debugging.html).

I was wondering if this feature is also available in JetBrains ReSharper for Visual Studio (2013/2015)?
At least I can't find an option to enable or a ReSharper extension which enables this feature..

Comment: They will soon publish Rider the C# IDE and that probably will support this kind of feature.

Comment: @LexLi That's nice, but I prefer Visual Studio for now.

Comment: extensions such as ozCode might fill the gaps.